# My update is not working, though it shows me the successful message

Tags: php, sql

My function is not working, though it shows the successful message that the data has been updated. But the data is still the same in the database also.

```
public function update(){
    $mysql = new Mysql();

    $query = "UPDATE module SET 
    modulename = '$this->name',
    modulecode = '$this->code',
    semesterid = '$this->semester',
    departmentid = '$this->department',
    programid = '$this->program'
    where moduleid = '$this->id';";

    $mysql->execute($query);
    if($mysql->result){
        $mysql->successMessage("Successfully Updated Data");
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $module = new Module($_POST);
    $module->update();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of **$this->id**?

Comment: There's no such thing as `$mysql->result`. You should get an error or warning for that line.

Comment: What is `new Mysql`? There's no `Mysql` class in PHP -- the OOP interfaces to MySQL are `PDO` and `Mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the number of rows affected by the query rather than the result.

Try mysql_affected_rows() to find out if anything was actually updated by the query.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use:

```
$query = "UPDATE module SET 
    modulename = '".$this->name."',
    modulecode = '".$this->code."',
    semesterid = '".$this->semester."',
    departmentid = '".$this->department."',
    programid = '".$this->program."'
    where moduleid = '".$this->id;
```

Comment: Why should this make a difference? Don't you know that PHP supports variable substitution inside double-quoted strings?

Comment: There is semicolon inside double quotes

Comment: AFAIK, that's not a problem. You can't have multiple statements, but you're allowed to have a semicolon at the end of the statement.